# How to start Tor with Windows 10

Tags: windows, tor-install

I downloaded the latest Tor/windows (tried v 6 and 7).  At college I can access a windows 7 machine, and it runs Tor fine from a usb key (I have only limited access privileges) - no settings changes.  On my Win 10 laptop, with no AV and no firewall, it won't even start - tried both Tor versions, on usb key or on desktop.  Only get the cannot connect to control port message flashed up.
Help please!
OwenH

Comment: Check antivirus software and windows application event logs.

Comment: No antivirus on the laptop!  I see no log events for the times I was trying Tor browser ...

Comment: Start a Wireshark capture , run the Tor browser and post the packet capture here. Shall take a look. Maybe the ISP is blocking ports.

Comment: Do not do this, your ISP blocking ports will never affect if a local process can run or not. That's utterly ridiculous.